# Is there a way to mirror iOS 9 screen to Ubuntu

Tags: mirrors

I want to mirror my iOS 9.3.5 screen to my Ubuntu 16.04.3.
Is that possible?
I tried to run reflecter with wine 3.1 but it did not work